# Using flexbox (order) to organize and order multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I created several divs with some checkboxes, I would like to change the position of each one using the flex box, more specifically the order function. Example:
Div: Age
Checkbox: new, old, baby

Div: Music
Checkbox: New music, Old music

I would like to put the music div first using only flex box order.

```
<div id="TEST" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="narrow-title odd">TEST</div>
                    <div class="odd">
                        <ul class="selec-design block-metal">
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST_2272" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST"><span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST_2239" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST_1796" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="TEST">
                                    <span></span>TEST<input type="checkbox" id="TEST_2237" name="TEST" value="TEST" style="display:none;">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Which one is "music?"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, never use an ID twice. They are meant to be unique.

Now, if you want to order elements using flex box, just give the child elements the `order` attribute in your CSS.

Here's an example using divs.  You may need to play with your display and position to get it to work with list items.

```css
#TEST {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#TEST ul, 
#TEST li {
  display: block;
}
#TEST1 {
  order: 1;
}
#TEST2 {
  order: 2;
}
#TEST3 {
  order: 3;
}
#TEST4 {
  order: 4;
}
#TEST5 {
  order: 5;
}
#TEST6 {
  order: 6;
}
#TEST7 {
  order: 7;
}
#TEST8 {
  order: 8;
}
```

```html
<div id="TEST" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div id="TEST1">TEST1 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
      <div id="TEST8">TEST8 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
      <div id="TEST2">TEST2 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
      <div id="TEST3">TEST3 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>      
      <div id="TEST5">TEST5 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
      <div id="TEST6">TEST6 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
      <div id="TEST7">TEST7 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
      <div id="TEST4">TEST4 
        <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="TEST">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it already gave me a light, but I don't want to sort the checkboxes, I want to sort the divs, inside the divs there are the checkboxes, I'm not being able to sort the divs, when I put flex-direction: columns they disappear , I don't know what may be causing this

Comment: Also links cannot contain inputs, it's invalid HTML

Comment: @Paulie_D Good call.  I just grabbed OP's code and wasn't paying attention to what was in there.  Updated.

Comment: @PabloBatista If you can update your code so it matches your question, i.e. "Div: Music Checkbox: New music, Old music", it will be easier to help you get it sorted out.